# How many different ways in Visual C# is there to read in a file?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. How many different ways are there to read in a text file? In Java there are several different ways to read in a file -- such as with Scanner, Bufferedread, Stringreader, ...etc...

What I would like to know is which is the fast and best way read in a text file.

Class 1:

```
public void readText1()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to write a program that can read in a text file a bunch of different ways.

Comment: Considering you could use an SMS client to text your buddy, and ask him to manually enter the contents of the file into a Perl script that  converts it into Morse code and transmits it via AM to a receiver on your system that relays it via UDP to a process that sends it to your C# application via Win32 messages....... there are a few ways to "read a file".

Comment: @Jonathon  Sounds like a classic Rube Goldberg implementation.

Comment: @MarkHall And I didn't even [use jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif)!

Comment: Do you have the pearl script that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about StreamReader. Use

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("TestFile.txt")
```

I believe it matches to Java's Scanner.

Comment: Which is the best way and the fastest way?

Comment: I believe they use the same Win32 API to do that. Usually the simplest interface it the fastest. So, System.IO.File.ReadAllText is a good choice

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Most file reading can be done there.

Comment: [Link-only answers are not valid answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Perhaps the problem isn't my answer, or  Rodrigo's answer. Perhaps the problem is the question.